# Context value seems not passed into ListView in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am learning following Django 1.7 tutorial in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial04/.
I copied code from web, then run it. I encounter two question:

1. After adding IndexView which inherits ListView, the 127.0.0.1:8000/polls page just returns "No polls are available." without any database items. I am confused by classed based view, seems the context value is not passed to template. 
   **----------> solved, this is my silly type mistake.**
2. get_queryset(), what is for, when this method is called, how does this map to context?  How does this function knows context mapping, what if there are two contexts and two values?

Could someone give me some guide here? thanks a lot.

polls/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),  #this url works
        url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    )
```

polls/views.py

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404,HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.template import RequestContext, loader
    from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
    from .models import Question, Choice
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    from django.views import generic


    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name ='polls/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'last_question_list'

        def get_queryset(self):
            return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    #this works
    #def index(request):     
    #    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    #    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    #   return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

polls/index.html

```
        {% if latest_question_list %}    <!-- seems here value is not passed by -->
            <ul>
            {% for question in latest_question_list %}
                <li>
                    {{ question.question_text }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>{{ latest_question_list }}</p>
            <p>No polls are available.</p>    <!-- always display this -->
            <p>{{ latest_question_list }}</p>
        {% endif %}
```

database

```
>>> from polls.models import Question
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: What's up?>, <Question: tttt>]
```

Comment: Note, that `context_object_name` is *'last_question_list'*, but in template you are checking *'la**te**st_question_list'*

Comment: Yes, solved. really silly mistake. But still how last_question_list mapped to context?  I guess via get_queryset(), but how does Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5] automatically linked to last_question_list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Django is Open Source, it is possible to determine, how `queryset` becomes available in template via `context_object_name` variable. Let's take a look at *django.views.generic.list.py*:

```
class MultipleObjectMixin(ContextMixin):
    # Some fields
    context_object_name = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get_queryset implementation

    def get_context_object_name(self, object_list):
        """
        Get the name of the item to be used in the context.
        """
        if self.context_object_name:
            return self.context_object_name
        elif hasattr(object_list, 'model'):
            return '%s_list' % object_list.model._meta.model_name
        else:
            return None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
        # Some stuff
        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
        # Some other stuff
        if context_object_name is not None:
            context[context_object_name] = queryset
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super(MultipleObjectMixin, self).get_context_data(**context)

    # And, of course, a lot of other functions


class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        # Some magic
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    # Skipped
```

When you are calling `get` method, Django initializes `self.object_list` with `get_queryset()`. Then, it calls `get_context_data()` and passes the context data to a template.

`MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data` returns a dictionary with `name->variable` pairs. It creates a pair `get_context_object_name()` -> `object_list`, and that is why you can access your list using defined `context_object_name` name.

Answer (score 0):

Class based views make the task of the developer a lot easier by providing a lot of pre-baked code. `ListView` is used to return a list of objects. ListView like all other views is extended from `View`. `View` implements a `get_context_data` method which is passes data to be used within the template. So, now if examine the `get_context_data` method of ListView, we find this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Get the context for this view.
    """
    queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
    page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
    context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
    if page_size:
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
        context = {
                'paginator': paginator,
                'page_obj': page,
                'is_paginated': is_paginated,
                'object_list': queryset
            }
    else:
        context = {
                'paginator': None,
                'page_obj': None,
                'is_paginated': False,
                'object_list': queryset
            }
    if context_object_name is not None:
        context[context_object_name] = queryset
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super(MultipleObjectMixin, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

As you can see, object_list is set to queryset or if you provide context_object_name, it is set to queryset. And queryset is set by the `get_queryset` defined by you.

I hope this makes the process clear.